# Open a databse in access that is being modified by a C# program

Tags: c#, ms-access

I asked a similar question but i dont think i was specific enough. I am making a program that lets the user update records in an access db. Once they are done updating the records, I added a button so they could open the same db they update and use a saved report wizard to print with.
The problem is I cannot get vs to open the db file. I can update the records just fine, but when i go to open the database, it opens the file that i used to make the data connection so it doesn't have the updated records.

So my question is, after i deploy the app, how can i make my button open up the database that the published version is updating ?

appologies, here is the code im using to open the database:

```
  Access.Application iAccess = null;
        // Start a new instance of Access for Automation:
        iAccess = new Access.Application();
        // Open a database in non-exclusive mode:            
        iAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase(@"Database\IBPDBFINISHED.accdb", false);
        iAccess.Visible = true;
```

When i use that code, i get an error saying that the db may be opened exclusively by another user, or may not exist, or may not be a .ADP file.

Is my app opening the database exclusively when im updating records?

Comment: Most likely you are not closing the OleDbConnection... However that is a guess because you provided no code at all. Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please also read [How do I ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: can´t you open the file, load into memory, and close the file so you can access it from everywhere else?

Comment: You probably have a mistake in your code.  In order to identify that, we would need to see your code.

Comment: Show code please.

Comment: I agree with Igor. You have to close the connection before you open the access file. Or you can use some reporting tool to generate the printable version of the report.

Comment: I tried adding: this.iBPDBFINISHEDDataSet.Dispose(); but im getting the same error still.